# Google maps not showing when clicking on href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have integrated google maps in one of my web app page(Say, pageA). Web app is implemented in RoR and I am working on localhost/development phase for now.

Interesting thing is that google map does not display correctly when I reach to pageA by clicking on some href link but it displays correctly when I refresh the page(pageA)

I do not know in which direction I should start by debugging. Is it browser or cache or something else?

I hope that code part does not have anything to do with this problem since it is opening while refreshing the page. Having said that, I would be happy to share the code part in case someone want to have a look at it.

Comment: Do you have turbolinks enabled?

Comment: @knuxus, Yes I do.

Comment: So the tricky thing is having that on ready function of loading maps, only execute when the page is truly loaded, or otherwise if you deactivate turbolinks for that link specifically, it could work...